# Why use an RSA public key exponent of form $2^n+1$ instead of $2^n-1$?

Tags: rsa

The short exponents in RSA which are only a few bits in length,i.e. $e=3,\ 17$ and $2^{16} +1$

Why we are using exponents of the form ${}2^n+1$ not $2^n-1$?

Comment: There is no actual *rule* about it but it would be nice if you would *accept* answers if they sufficiently answer your question. You can hit accept by hitting the V mark next to the answer. If there is anything missing, don't hesitate to ask for clarification (but don't ask a *separate* question in the comments).

Answer (score 10):

The keys of form $2^n + 1$ only contain two bits set (the ones in your question are also short prime values, in case you didn't notice). The public exponents of form $2^n - 1$ on the other hand contain a lot of bits set when $n$ grows (the value 3 is obviously both `10 + 1` in binary as well as `100 - 1` in binary).

Modular exponentiation is usually *deemed* more efficient if only a few bits are set. At least it is easier to see how to implement it efficiently. The public exponent is usually a prime [to make it easier to find a value of $p$ where the public exponent is relative prime to $p - 1$](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2339/2651).

Note that $2^{16}+1= 1\ 0000\ 0000\ 0000\ 0001b$ and $2^{16}-1=1111\ 1111\ 1111\ 1111b$. So there is quite a difference in the number of bits set (2 against 16). As the value is 65535 in decimal, it is quite obviously not a prime either as it divides by 5. Then again, $2^{17} - 1 = 1\ 1111\ 1111\ 1111\ 1111b$ is prime and contains as many bits.

The primes with just 2 bits set (the first and last one) are called Fermat primes. There are currently five known Fermat primes:
$$F_0 = 2^{1} + 1 = 3$$
$$F_1 = 2^{2} + 1 = 5$$
$$F_2 = 2^{4} + 1 = 17$$
$$F_3 = 2^{8} + 1 = 257$$
$$F_4 = 2^{16} + 1 = 65537$$
if there are any others (this is an open math problem) they will most definitely not be *small* primes.

---

For comparison, try to calculate both $6\times999$ and $6\times1001$ in normal decimals. It is easy to see why this calculation is efficient.

**[EDIT]** I did do some performance measurements on Java 8 build 71 and I did not find a (consistent) difference between Fermat and Mersenne primes. This could be due to the information that Poncho provided:

> Note: $e=2^{16}+1$ can be computed with 16 squarings and 1 multiplication; $e=2^{16}−1$ can be computed with 15 squarings and 4 multiplications; calling the former 'much more efficient' appears to be a bit of an exaggeration...

But it could also be due to side channel protection in the Java runtime. In the end it will depend on the implementation as well. *It does seem to show a common misconception that Fermat primes should always be (much) faster than other primes*. I would not be surprised if Fermat primes are just more entrenched than other values.

---

The following are the known Mersenne primes (values that are both prime and of form $2^{n}-1$) up to $2^{31}-1$.

$$2^{3}-1 = 7$$
$$2^{5}-1 = 31$$
$$2^{7}-1 = 127$$
$$2^{13}-1 = 8191$$
$$2^{17}-1 = 131071$$
$$2^{19}-1 = 524287$$
$$2^{31}-1 = 2147483647$$

I'll be surprised if I see a use for these Mersenne primes as public exponent within RSA though.

Comment: In fact, [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) of the form $2^n-1$ seem quite a bit more common than [Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number), of which we currently know only five examples (3, 5, 17, 257 and 65537). But, as you correctly note, they're also much less useful as RSA exponents.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for the tip about Mersenne primes. *Afterwards* you always remember you already know about these kind of things :)

Comment: Note: $e = 2^{16}+1$ can be computed with 16 squarings and 1 multiplication; $e = 2^{16}-1$ can be computed with 15 squarings and 4 multiplications; calling the former 'much more efficient' appears to be a bit of an exaggeration...

Comment: @poncho right you are. Actually, it seems that although this seems to be the main reason for using a Fermat prime instead of a Mersenne prime, i did not see any noticable difference on my Java platform. Then again, thats also implementation specific, e.g. I don't know if there are side channel protection measures used even though public key is used; it could use the same modular exponentiation as for privete key ops without CRT.

Comment: I suspect the real reason Fermat primes are used is mostly because of convention; it's obvious how to minimize the multiplications (while the 19 operation I listed for $2^{16}-1$ might not occur to a naive implementor); and given there's no other reason, well, that's what people pick.  As for side channel attacks, well, the value $e$ is public, and so it's not like we need to hide the squaring/multiplication order...